# How to store data in XML file in Android using Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm developing an android app in xamarin using .net. I'm stuck to a very simple query, I just want to store simple data in XML file. I haven't started with any code I'm not getting any clue to start with it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreference to store value into android Ex:

```
SharedPreference sp=getSharedPreferences("XML Name(In which name you have to create xml file)",1);
Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("Key","Value what to you want to save");
editor.commit();
```

I hope this will help to you :)

Comment: Can you provide me small snippet

Comment: Does it help to you :)

Comment: The XML file is still empty, I've written following code

Comment: ISharedPreferences prefs = this.GetSharedPreferences("EmptyXmlFile.xml",FileCreationMode.Append);
    var editor = prefs.Edit();
    editor.PutString("name","ABC");
    editor.PutString("surname","XYZ");
    editor.Commit();

Comment: And my XML <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<note>
 <name></name>
 <surname></surname>
</note>

Comment: don't need to give extention of xml.Just put filename only.

Comment: That is not ISharedPreference.That is SharedPreference

Comment: SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("EmptyXmlFile",1); Editor editor = prefs.Edit(); editor.PutString("name","ABC"); editor.PutString("surname","XYZ"); editor.Commit();

Comment: In xamarin its ISharedPreferences. And also I removed .xml extension. But its still not working for me.

Comment: where should i keep the XML file? In which folder, Now I have saved the file in Asset folder

Comment: You don't need to create xml file.SharedPreference automatically create and store the value on it

Comment: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-shared-preferences-example_12.html view this link :)